# JSF/Primefaces issue when form field rendering depends on selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, page-refresh, update-attribute

Form field rendering is depending on selected item in selectOneMenu.

Page:

```
  <h:body>
    <f:view>
      <h:form>

        <h:panelGrid>
          <p:inputText value="#{user.username}"/>
          <p:selectOneMenu value="#{user.moreInputs}"
                           required="true">
            <p:ajax event="change"
                    update="moreInputGrid"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue=""/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{user.selectItems}"/>
          </p:selectOneMenu>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGrid id="moreInputGrid">
          <p:inputText rendered="#{user.renderMoreInputs}"
                       value="#{user.name}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton action="#{user.register}"
                         value="Register user"/>

      </h:form>
    </f:view>
  </h:body>
```

Backing bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class User {
  private String username;
  private MoreInputs moreInputs;
  private String name;

  public enum MoreInputs {
    YES,
    NO
  }

  public boolean isRenderMoreInputs() {
    return (moreInputs == MoreInputs.YES);
  }

  public SelectItem[] getSelectItems() {
    SelectItem[] items = new SelectItem[2];
    items[0] = new SelectItem(
                      MoreInputs.YES,
                      "yes");
    items[1] = new SelectItem(
                      MoreInputs.NO,
                      "no");

    return items;
  }

  public String register() {
    return null;
  }

  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  public MoreInputs getMoreInputs() {
    return moreInputs;
  }

  public void setMoreInputs(MoreInputs moreInputs) {
    this.moreInputs = moreInputs;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Issue arrises if the client does page refresh after choosing an item causing form fields to render. Such form fields will not be rendered on page refresh, although they should. Plus, if client then tries to submit form, validation is skipped for those hidden fields and form is successfully processed.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there an elegant solution?

Comment: What is the scope to user bean? If it is in RequestScoped, than change it to SessionScoped.

Comment: Works with SessionScoped bean, it was ViewScoped, but shouldn't it work with ViewScoped? Because it doesn't make any sense to put user account created by admin in session scope...

Comment: It should work with view scope. It's also the only right scope for this case. The session scope is not the right scope. Your symptoms suggest that the view scoped bean is recreated on every request for some reason. Put a debug breakpoint on constructor to be sure. If it's indeed invoked on every single HTTP request on the same view (which is wrong), then please post an SSCCE. Then we can point out the cause. One of the most common causes is that you're binding a property of a view scoped bean to an attribute of a taghandler while you're using a Mojarra version older than 2.1.18.

Comment: You're right, bean constructor is called on page refresh. Added details to code. Mojarra version is 2.2.0

Comment: 2.2.0 is still in beta. Use it only if you're developing/testing for Mojarra itself. For production, use the newest 2.1.x instead.

Comment: Tried with 2.1.1, no difference. I'll try with the newest 2.1.x

Comment: Hm... Looked at PrimeFaces showcase select example: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprSelect.jsf and the showcase code - PPRBean is ViewScoped and it has the same problem. PrimeFaces bug?

Comment: NetBeans 7.2.1, Tomcat, Mojarra 2.1.23, still no difference. Tried with h:selectOneMenu instead of p:selectOneMenu, same thing...

Comment: doesn't a click on 'refresh page' recreate a bean by default? If it shouldn't, then I have the same problem !!